# Rotating point (anchor) for SpriteComponent

Tags: flutter, flame

I'm playing around with Flame and Flutter and trying to add a SpriteComponent that rotates around its center. I'm a beginner, so bare with me.

It works when I do the following:

```
class Player extends SpriteComponent with HasGameRef<MyGame> {
  Player({required this.sprite}) : super();

  final Sprite sprite;
  late SpriteComponent player;

  @override
  FutureOr<void> onLoad() {
    player = SpriteComponent(
      sprite: sprite,
      position: Vector2(0, 0),
      size: Vector2(150, 80),
      anchor: Anchor.center,
    );
    debugMode = true;
    add(player);
    return super.onLoad();
  }

  @override
  void update(double dt) {
    angle += 0.01;
    super.update(dt);
  }
}
```

So it looks like so:

[image]

But when I want to move the Sprite a bit and add the line:

```
position: Vector2(200, 200),
```

[image]

And now it rotates still around the corner on the top...how do I rotate the Sprite in its own center?

Sorry, if it is a trivial question, but I can't figure it out for hours...thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `SpriteComponent` inside of your `Player` component (which is also a `SpriteComponent`), since you are using the same sprite on both of those components I'm fairly certain you only want one of those.

If you remove the inner `player` you'll end up with something like this, which should be what you want:

```dart
class Player extends SpriteComponent with HasGameRef<MyGame> {
  Player({required this.sprite}) : super(
    position: Vector2(0, 0),
    size: Vector2(150, 80),
    anchor: Anchor.center,
  );

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() {
    super.onLoad();
    debugMode = true;
  }

  @override
  void update(double dt) {
    super.update(dt);
    angle += 0.01;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It makes sense now! It was a long day yesterday :)

Comment: @webwurm we've all been there! I can recommend joining our Discord if you want help with these kind of issues faster :)
https://discord.com/invite/pxrBmy4